# How can I execute Ruby code with WEBrick instead of dumping the code to my browser?

Tags: ruby, windows, webrick

I'm facing a problem when I run my program in a browser with the [WEBrick server](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html). It shows me my code as written in the 2loop.rb file.

When I run `ruby -run -e -httpd. -p 5000` at the command prompt, and load `http://localhost:5000/2loop.rb` in the browser, it shows the code from 2loop.rb instead of running it.

How can I execute the 2loop.rb program instead?

Comment: You should check out something like `sinatra`.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

You're doing this to yourself by serving your current working directory as the root of your web server. You aren't actually running the code in your file; you're just telling [WEBrick](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) to serve any file you name in the URI. `http://localhost:5000/2loop.rb` will serve "2loop.rb" as text/html in your posted example.

### Using un.rb

The flag you're using isn't actually "run." Instead, the `-r` flag actually loads a module, which in this case is the [un.rb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/un/rdoc/un_rb.html) module. Using un.rb to start WEBrick is done like this:

```
$ ruby -run -e httpd . -p 5000
```

and starts a web server in the document root. In this case, the dot means to use the current working directory as the root. This is not really what you want to start code you've placed inside a Ruby file.

### Running WEBrick Programmatically

Using some snippets from the [WEBrick documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html), you will see that you can create a file named "2loop.rb" containing the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start
```

This will serve files out of the /tmp/public_html directory on port 5000, which you can reach at `http://localhost:5000`. You can then make the file executable and start the server with `./2loop.rb`, or just run `ruby 2loop.rb` if you don't want to make your file executable for some reason.

If you don't want WEBrick just to serve files, you will have to [add custom behavior](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html#module-WEBrick-label-Custom+Behavior) to your web server inside the 2loop.rb script. This is a fairly low-level thing to do, but may suit your needs.

### Sensible Alternatives

You should probably use a web framework like [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) or [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you don't want to have write all the low-level behaviors yourself. Sinatra in particular is a very lightweight alternative. This example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sinatra'
set :port, 5000
get '/hello' do
  "Hello, World!"
end
```

will create a URL at `http://localhost:5000/hello` with a custom action that returns "Hello, World!" as an in-browser response.

Comment: Hi this is not working 

I have run this command in command prompt 
"ruby -run -e httpd . -p 5000"
-------
after open browser with my file.. 
which i have write down this code --------------
require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start

ary = {  "0"=>"fred", "1"=>10, "2"=>3.14, "3"=>"This is a string", "4"=>"last element", }
ary.each do |key, value|
   puts  "#{key} #{value}"
end

It show me as it is :(

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd suggest you to use [Common Gateway Interface (CGI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). Let me provide you an example.

**Firstly**, create a file named `server.rb`:

```
require 'webrick'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  :Port => 6789, # a server's port
  :DocumentRoot => File.join(Dir.pwd, "/scripts") # a folder with scripts
)
server.start
```

**Secondly**, create a folder `scripts` and put the following file (`the_best_program.cgi`) into it. Note the `.cgi` extension. It matters. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241341/for-ruby-webrick-i-need-windows-to-recognize-shebang-notation) for details on the first line of the script (shebang) if you are working under Windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
require 'cgi'
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n" 
5.times { |i| puts "Hello world #{i}!"}
puts 'So many worlds there. :('
```

**Finally**,

- Launch your server from command-line (`ruby server.rb`).
- Start browser and go to `localhost:6789/the_best_program.cgi` (or `0.0.0.0:6789/the_best_program.cgi`)
- Enjoy!

### Notes

- You might need to change permissions to your scripts folder / script. On unix-like system do: `chmod 755 scripts scripts/the_best_program.cgi`.
- You can launch not only ruby scripts this way.