# how to excute code on webrick server

Tags: ruby, webrick

I start a `webrick` server like this:

```
dell@dev:/var/www/ruby$ ruby -run  -httpd. -p 5000
```

and have this code in `abc.rb`:

```
require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start

ary = {  "0"=>"fred", "1"=>10, "2"=>3.14, "3"=>"This is a string", "4"=>"last element", }
ary.each do |key, value|
   puts  "#{key} #{value}"
end
```

When I run this code it shows me the same code on browser

```
http://localhost:5000/abc.rb
```

How can I view the output this code, I have already asked this question and did not get any correct answer :(

Is it the right code? I want to know this, where this code place

```
require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start
```

if any one give me step by step ans to run this code i am very thankful.. I don't understand the ans :( how to do this

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html#module-WEBrick-label-Custom+Behavior):

> The easiest way to have a server perform custom operations is through
>   `WEBrick::HTTPServer#mount_proc`. The block given will be called with a
>   `WEBrick::HTTPRequest` with request info and a `WEBrick::HTTPResponse`
>   which must be filled in appropriately:
>
> ```
> server.mount_proc '/' do |req, res|
>   res.body = 'Hello, world!'
> end
> ```
>
> Remember that `server.mount_proc` must `server.start`.

So:

```
require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

server.mount_proc '/abc.rb' do |req, res|
  ary = {  "0"=>"fred", "1"=>10, "2"=>3.14, "3"=>"This is a string", "4"=>"last element" }
  res.body = ary.map do |key, value|
     "#{key} #{value}"
  end.join("\n")
end

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start
```

Also, I believe the correct way to start your `WebBrick` is by running:

```
ruby abc.rb
```

Comment: :( No i have change my file code now as it you

"require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

server.mount_proc '/abc.rb' do |req, res|
  ary = {  "0"=>"fred", "1"=>10, "2"=>3.14, "3"=>"This is a string", "4"=>"last element" }
  res.body = ary.map do |key, value|
     "#{key} #{value}"
  end.join("\n")
end

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start"

it's not working

Comment: Please provide me step by step if you can

Comment: Did you run it as I suggested (`ruby abc.rb`)?

Comment: I have not knowledge about ubuntu I am new.. I want to run my code on server what will i do

Comment: I have just install ruby on ubuntu now, I have run code on browser "http://localhost:5000/abc.rb" but it show me code file on browser :(

Comment: i have just write down this code on abc.rb file -------------------------------
require 'webrick'

root   = File.path '/tmp/public_html'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => root

server.mount_proc '/abc.rb' do |req, res|
  ary = {  "0"=>"fred", "1"=>10, "2"=>3.14, "3"=>"This is a string", "4"=>"last element" }
  res.body = ary.map do |key, value|
     "#{key} #{value}"
  end.join("\n")
end

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start

Comment: I suggest that you should take the time to _read_ and _understand_ the answers that people already gave you(http://stackoverflow.com/a/22438093/1120015). If you feel you don't have enough knowledge, _stop_ and _learn_ the domain you are working one. People have invested time in answering you, you should invest at least as much to take the most out of them.

Comment: this works if you save the code above in eg server.rb and start this with "ruby server.rb" in the browser then type "http://localhost:5000/abc.rb" in the adressbar
However i advise to take a look at sinatra where this can be done a lot easier and with more possibilities